# ONOS Rest API Configuration

Tags: onos

I am working on ONOS Virtual Box instance version 3.0.3. I am unable to configure the Swagger auto generated API documentation using the standard uri http://>/v1/docs. I have been able to install POSTER extension and can do GET / HEADER method call using the REST API but getting an 405 method not allowed on PUT/ DELETE. Can anyone please help me enable DELETE/PUT methods in the ONOS instance.

Answer (score 1):

ONOS supports those methods. if you get any faults it might be your client's fault.

besides you get 4xx http error and these kind of errors show that the problem is in the client side.

watch this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GohTQ.jpg)